# 折り返し位置を改善したい。

Tags: html, css

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
上の画像は、文字が折返し位置がバラバラになっています。

読みやすさとのトレードオフかもしれませんが
右余白の不揃い感を改善したいのです。
どのようにすれば良いでしょうか。

追記:
質問者が求めるイメージについては、質問に対するコメントのやりとりにあります。

Comment: リンクが張られていないようですので、リンクをお願いします。

Comment: どういう状態を期待して実際どうなっているのかが「折り返し地点がバラバラ」だけではわからないので、スクリーンショットを貼っていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: @だいじん さん　レス有り難うございます。すみません、記入が途中の状態で忘れていました。リンク先を記載させて頂きました。お時間ある時にお願いします(><)
@ unarist さん レス有り難うございます。添付しました。左側も少しズレていますが特に右側がバラバラな状態です。

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lJV5C.png の上半分のようになっているのを、下半分のようにしたい、ということであってますか？

Comment: おそらく右側の「下さ　」とか「下さい。　　　」「DDや　」という空白の量の乱れのことを指摘しているのかなと思いますが……。 「左が少しズレている」というのがわかりませんし、折り返し位置は適切だと思いますが(プロポーショナルですし)。

Comment: @  unarist　さん　レス有り難うございます!！まさにそんな感じです。

Comment: @Norikaz Ishii さん　すいません、「左が少しズレている」は私の間違いでした。確かに読みやすいとは思うのですが、画面全体で見た時に不揃い間が目立つので、美しくないかなと思っています。

Comment: @いっちゃん 質問修正のレビュー中ですが。回答投稿がオープンされる前に、text-align: justify;(均等割)を試してみてください。おそらく大分改善されると思うのですが。

Comment: @NorikazIshii 「読みやすさとのトレードオフかもしれませんが」という一文が加えられているのは「確かに読みやすいとは～」というコメントからでしょうか？トレードオフとまでは言っていないかと。

Comment: @unarist ああ。そこは「確かに読みやすいとは思うのですが、画面全体で見た時に不揃い間が目立つので」というコメントのやりとりからです。蛇足かと言われると確かにという気もしますが。読みやすさよりも不揃いをなんとかしたい点を強調するために必要かなと感じたので修正に入れました。

Comment: あれ? 回答できない...
`text-align: justify` のことではないでしょうか?
http://jsbin.com/hamekanifo/1/edit

Comment: @mysticatea さん　レス有り難うございます。フォントの問題じゃなかったんですね。恥ずかしながら今理解しました。

Answer (score 3):

両端揃えにすることで解決します。
両端揃えは、CSSのtext-align: justify;にて設定出来ます。
（IEではtext-justifly: inter-ideograph;なので両方書きます。）

以下、例。

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                width: 200px;
                text-align: justify;
                text-justify: inter-ideograph;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            吾輩は猫である。名前はまだ無い。<br>
            どこで生れたか頓（とん）と見當がつかぬ。<br>
            何でも薄暗いじめじめした所でニヤーニヤー泣いて居た事丈は記憶して居る。<br>
            吾輩はこゝで始めて人間といふものを見た。<br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```